# Getting documents of last 25 minutes with formula and lotusscript

Tags: formula, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

In lotus I have a view with order documents.
I am building an agent to search for all orders which are modified in the last 25 minutes.

For this I have done code like:

```
strFormule = "Form=""Order"" & @Modified >=  @Adjust(@Today;0;0;0;0;-25;0) & Deleted !=""J"""

Set ndcOrder = currentDB.Search( strFormule, Nothing, 0 )
If ndcOrder.Count <> 0 Then
Set doc = ndcOrder.GetFirstDocument
While Not doc Is Nothing
```

So if it is 11.00 then it need to take orders which are modified today from 10.35

But in the debugger I also get orders which where modified 2 hours earlier.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's might be because you're using @today which doesn't have a time element. Try @Now instead ?

Comment: So If i want the orders from last day then i use today and if i want from the last hour or minute then i use now right?

Comment: yes, that's right , or you could use @Date(@Modified) = @Yesterday (just compares the date part of the timestamp) for yesterday's modifications. If time of day plays a part then use @ Modified = @ Adjust(@Now;0;0;0;0;-25;0), as you say.

Comment: @bboni Behind the curtain, Lotus Notes stores a specific date/time as a number, and backstage, @Today = @Integer(@Now), and noon today is @Today + 0.5.  (Don't try that in formula language, it won't work, but you can play with it in LotusScript if you want to.)@Today is midnight this morning. Therefore,  `@Adjust(@Today;0;0;0;0;-25;0)` will always be 11:35 PM the previous night, no matter what time you do it.

Answer (score 3):

In the past I used the LotusScript method GetModifiedDocuments which lets you specify a NotesDateTime object to retrieve any document modified since.
Your code could then look like this:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim dc As notesdocumentcollection
Dim since As New NotesDateTime("")

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Call since.SetNow()
Call since.AdjustMinute(-25)
Set dc = db.GetModifiedDocuments(since)
```

My experience with this method was very good so far. More info on [GetModifiedDocuments](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETMODIFIEDDOCUMENTS_METHOD_DB.html)

Comment: Good point. Or you could use that `since` variable in the db.Search. It would be a **much** faster search that way.

Answer (score 0):

Why use formula at all?
I would create a hidden view, first column is last modified date-time, sorted descending.
Then I would write my Lotusscript code to start at the top and work its way down until it encounters a date/time value that is older than 25 minutes ago.

Something like this:

```
Dim docs List As NotesDocument
Set dt25 = New NotesDateEntry(Now())
Call dt25.AdjustMinutes(-25)
Dim col as NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim entry as NotesViewEntry
Set col = view.AllEntries
Set entry = col.GetFirstEntry
Do Until entry Is Nothing
    If Cdat(entry.ColumnValues(0))<Cdat(dt25.LSLocalTime) Then
        Exit Loop
    End If
    Set docs(entry.Document.UniversalID) = entry.Document
Loop
' Now you have a list of documents created in the last 25 minutes.
```